# Google spreadsheets: compare text from different tabs

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, array-formulas

There are two tabs, each one contain a list of links (column B) and a list of titles (column M). I need to check titles from column M and state if they match or not (TRUE or FALSE).

Here is the doc https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U6Kpf7fwyiRat9XsRKyBQb8ZO_qhD8QgO4athC8zfuU/edit?usp=sharing

I am using arrayformula for this, but for some reason it failed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(B2:B="",,VLOOKUP(B2:B,Live!B:M,COLUMNS(Live!B:M),FALSE)=M2:M))
```

Comment: thanks. looks like there is an issue. these are parts of links, not full links. could it be simply B2:B:  =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="",,REGEXMATCH(IMPORTXML(B2:B,"//head/title"),SUBSTITUTE(M2:M,"|","\|"))))

Comment: I do not need to scrape the titles, since they are already in the column M

Comment: So match `M` with what?

Comment: match columns M from live and and staging tabs, taking into account that data from M is connected to the urls from columns B on both tabs. And the urls are located randomly.

Comment: e.g. column B on each tab - there is /en/about/. I need to check if this url has got the same title on Live and Staging tabs.

Comment: Updated. Please check.